# Using Gestures with Switch Case (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement, gesture

I am new to creating apps for the iOS. Recently, I've been working on making a calculator app based on gestures. I am using switch cases to change operations, and I originally had it rigged up with buttons, but now I want to use gestures. Here is my code so far. The opAddition function is the first way I tried it, but it wouldn't switch functions. For example, if I wanted to switch from addition to subtraction, it would only work after the number was inputed. That's why I tried to use Switch-Case, but now I don't know how to link up gestures to them.

```
@implementation ABViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    calculatorScreen.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.notification.layer.cornerRadius = 90;
    self.notification.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.notification.alpha = 0;
    [[self.notification layer] setBorderWidth:8.0f];
    [[self.notification layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark - buttons

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender{
    currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (int)[sender tag];
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", currentNumber];

    if ( number.length < 11) {
        calculatorScreen.text =  number;
    }
};


#pragma mark - operator button code

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender{
    if (currentOperation == 0) { result = currentOperation; }
    else {

        if (_operationSimple.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){

            currentOperation = 1;

        } else if (_operationSimple.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown){

            currentOperation = 2;

        }

        switch (currentOperation) {

            case 1:
                result = result + currentNumber;
                self.notificationText.text = @"+";
                [self notify];
                break;
            case 2:
                result = result - currentNumber;
                self.notificationText.text = @"-";
                [self notify];
                break;
            case 3:
                result = result * currentNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                result = result / currentNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentOperation = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    currentNumber = 0;
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", result];
    if ( [sender tag] == 0) { result = 0; }
    currentNumber = [sender tag];

};

#pragma mark - Cancelations

-(IBAction)cancelInput{
    currentNumber = 0;
    self.notificationText.text = @"C";
    [self notify];
    calculatorScreen.text = @"0.0";
    result = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"Cancel Input");
}

-(IBAction)cancelOperation{
    currentNumber = 0;
    self.notificationText.text = @"AC";
    [self notify];
    calculatorScreen.text = @"0.0";
    currentOperation = 0;
    NSLog(@"Clear Operation");
}


double newresult = 0;

#pragma mark - Operations

-(IBAction)opAddition{
    result = result + currentNumber;
    self.notificationText.text = @"+";
    [self notify];
    newresult = result;
    currentNumber = 0;
    NSLog(@"Number Added. New result:");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", newresult]);
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", result];
}

#pragma mark - notification stuffs
- (void)notify{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.notification.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.notification.alpha = 0.0f;
    }];
}

@end
```